# jquery bind an event handler to multiple elements with containing element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind an event handler to multiple elements (with a containing element self.el) using jQuery.

Is the below code correct ?

```
$("input", "textarea", "select", self.el).on("keyup", function(e) {
                    if($.keys[e.keyCode] != "TAB") {
                        self.callChangeAction(e);
                    }
                })
```

Comment: `Is the below code correct ?` Why not testing it???

Comment: Do you want to handle events of (inputs, textareas, selects AND self.el) or (inputs, textareas, selects INSIDE self.el). Your question is confusing!

Comment: i want to handle events on all inputs, textareas, selects (all of them having parent self.el)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(self.el).on("keyup", "input, textarea, select", function(e) {
    if ($.keys[e.keyCode] != "TAB") {
        self.callChangeAction(e);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle events on inputs, textareas, selects AND self.el:

```
$("input, textarea, select").add(self.el).on(...)
```

Handle events on inputs, textareas, selects that CONTAIN self.el (which does not make much sense):

```
$("input, textarea, select").has(self.el).on(...)
```

Handle events on inputs, textareas, selects that are INSIDE self.el at the beginning:

```
$("input, textarea, select", self.el).on(...)
//alternative: 
$(self.el).find("input, textarea, select").on(...)
```

Handle events on any inputs, textareas, selects that will be INSIDE self.el at the time the event fires:

```
$(self.el).on(events, "input, textarea, select", ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to bind the event handler to all of the elements *individually* then instead of a list of selectors, you should use a single comma-separated selector:

```
$('select,input,textarea', self.el).on(...)
```

which itself is just a short-hand for `.find`:

```
$(self.el).find('select,input,textarea').on(...)
```

Alternatively, assuming that the event you wish to catch is one that "bubbles up", you could use *event delegation*, whereby the parent element catches the event on behalf of all of its children, and then jQuery checks the actual element in which the event happened to find out whether it's one that you wanted:

```
$(self.el).on('keyup', 'select,input,textarea', ...);
```